# Align two buttons at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to align two buttons at the bottom of the page, but I can not do it. One is the button "gallery" and the other is icon linkedin.

```
<div class="container fill">
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item">    
    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://www.mysite/images/category/image.jpg');background-position: center;">
   <div class="container">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h1>TITLE</h1>
      <p class="lead">Description</p>
    </div> 
</div>
 <div class="pull-right">
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="categories.php?id=17">View Gallery</a>
 </div>
  </div>
   </div>
     </div>
 <div class="pull-left">
  <div class="social-caption">
      <button class="btn btn-large btn-linkedin">
       <i class="icon-linkedin"></i><span><a style="color:white" vhref="http://www.linkedin.com/"> | Linkedin</span></button>
      </div>
```

css for the two buttons:

```
.social-caption {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  bottom: 45px;
  left: 5px;
}


.gallery-button { 
  background-color: transparent; 
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px; 
  bottom: 45px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

The two buttons do not appear aligned. This problem is seen especially with mobile devices

Solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/nFw8E/)**, for example. It uses `position:absolute` to locate the buttons at the bottom of the page's content (`bottom:0`) - or relative to their parents positioning (in this case the `body`. The alternative would be to use `position:fixed` which would ensure the buttons appear at the bottom of the viewport at all times.

See the difference between [absolute positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/nFw8E/1/) and [fixed positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/nFw8E/2/).

HTML

```
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
```

CSS

```
body{
    position:relative;
}
button{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;        
}
button:last-child{
    left:100px;
}
```

Comment: I prefer the option position: fixed, and it works thanks! but how do I place the two buttons at the center bottom of the page?

Comment: You can add

```
<div class="to-bottom">
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
</div>
```

.to-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

May be you could use this:

```
<input type='button' style='position:fixed; top:94%; left:82%; width:100px' value='
```

this means the button will appear at the right corner in the bottom of your page.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //hope so this code helps you.

.center{
 justify-content: center;
 display:flex;
 align-item: center
}

.right{
    justify-content: flex-end;
    display:flex;
 }

//for center align
<div class="center">
    <button>First Button</button>
    <button>Second Button</button>
</div>

//for right align
<div class="right">
    <button>First Button</button>
    <button>Second Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add some further explanation on how this code works and what it does?